# TeleBot how to use bot.polling and other functions

Tags: python, telegram-bot

When I use bot.polling() the timed_messages never get called
is there a way to make this thing work
that way I can look for sent messages and send a timed automatic message

```
import telebot
import cryptocompare
from datetime import datetime

API_KEY = ""
bot = telebot.TeleBot(API_KEY)

@bot.message_handler(regexp="bitcoin")
def bitcoin(message):
    price = cryptocompare.get_price('BTC', 'USD')
    bot.reply_to(message, price['BTC']['USD'])

def timed_messages(prices, current_time):
    if current_time == "9:00:00":
        bot.send_message(-1001236909935, "Good Morning (9:00): \n" + prices)
    if current_time == "12:00:00":
        bot.send_message(-1001236909935, "Good Afternoon (12:00): \n" + prices)
    if current_time == "15:00:00":
        bot.send_message(-1001236909935, "Good Afternoon (15:00): \n" + prices)
    if current_time == "18:00:00":
        bot.send_message(-1001236909935, "Good Evening (18:00): \n" + prices)
    if current_time == "00:00:00":
        bot.send_message(-1001236909935, "Good Night (00:00): \n" + prices)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    while True:
        now = datetime.now()
        current_time = now.strftime("%H:%M:%S")
        prices = "Bitcoin: " + str(1) + "\n" + "DogeCoin: " + str(2) + "\n" + "HNT: " + str(3)
        timed_messages(prices, current_time)
        bot.polling()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `asyncio` to achieve what you want.

import it first

```py
import asyncio
```

Then change your code like this:

```py
async def timed_messages_worker():
    while True:
            now = datetime.now()
            current_time = now.strftime("%H:%M:%S")
            prices = "Bitcoin: " + str(1) + "\n" + "DogeCoin: " + str(2) + "\n" + "HNT: " + str(3)
            timed_messages(prices, current_time)
            await asyncio.sleep(1)

            
asyncio.create_task(timed_messages_worker)          
asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(bot.polling())
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use **asyncio** with **[Asynchronous version of telebot](https://github.com/eternnoir/pyTelegramBotAPI#asynctelebot)**